# Bundle a gemfile for Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, bundler

I have this file:

source :rubygems

gem 'sinatra', '1.3.1'
group :development do
   gem 'rspec', '2.7.0'
   gem 'cucumber', '1.1.3'
   gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

and I am trying to run from cmd.exe the command: bundle to install the gems from this file. On the screen is displayed the message: "Could not find the Gemfile".

The command must be ran from the root of the project, but I don't know why it does not work. Here is my project 'C:\Test\Cash Withdrawal' and I have the Gemfile here and does not work. Please tell me where I have to put the Gemfile and from what directory I have to run the gemfile. THX!

Answer (score 0):

Bundle command expects a presence of a file name "Gemfile". So if your project Directory is " C:\Test\Cash Withdrawal", make sure following

- You have a file name "Gemfile" in "C:\Test\Cash Withdrawal" directory.
- While executing "bundle install" your current directory is "C:\Test\Cash Withdrawal".